# Where to find the undo list?

Tags: modeling

How do I get the list of operations done in blender? Usually Undo/redo are found under edit menu. But I'm not able to locate undo list.

[This wiki page](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Vitals/Undo_and_Redo) says by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> it should show history. But somehow I'm not able to view it.

Note: I'm new to blender.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>. That wiki page is for Blender 2.4x.

Here's the [2.6x page](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Vitals/Undo_and_Redo#Undo_History) (which is current for 2.7x, as there is no 2.7x wiki yet)

If you want to access it from a menu, it's in *3D view > Header > Object*:

[image]

If you want to access it from a toolbar, it's in *3D view > Toolshelf* (<kbd>T</kbd>) *> Tool > History*:

[image]