# Where is the redo function in Blender?

Tags: interface

I have had several occasions where I went astray with my Blender work and had to undo my work or start over.  When I undid my work today that took several hours, I went too far.  Oops!  Now I have to redo that work.

I come to Blender from CAD, specifically AutoCAD and Inventor.  Both of those packages have a redo function in them.

I would really like to see one of you smart programmers work on that.  Or, tell me that it is available and I just don't see it.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/12217/1853 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14739/where-to-find-the-undo-list

Answer (score 9):

There is!:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> is **Undo**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> is **Redo**.

And <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> is to show and select **Undo History**.

Comment: The option to redo is greyed out after I undo.